# Db2 trigger referencing same table on which this before insert trigger is created

Tags: triggers, db2, user-defined-functions

In Db2 version 10.x, I have created a before insert trigger on table TEST

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TEST_INSERT
 BEFORE INSERT ON TEST 
 REFERENCING NEW AS OBJ
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
 WHEN (((SELECT CheckCount('SELECT count(1) FROM TEST') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)));
```

and this function:

```
--FUNCTION
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckCount(query varchar(1000)) 
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL 
 dfl:BEGIN 
 DECLARE id INTEGER;

DECLARE cur CURSOR for st1;
 PREPARE st1 FROM query;
 open cur;
 fetch from cur into id;
 return id;
 close cur;
END dfl*/
```

I am calling a udf to check the count on same table. But I am getting below error SQLCODE=-746, SQLSTATE=57053

> SQL0746N  The routine named "" (specific name
> "") failed because the routine violated nested SQL
> statement rules when attempting to perform operation ""
> on the table named "".
>
> Explanation:
>
> This message is returned when an application calls a routine that
> attempts to access a table in a way that conflicts with other uses of
> the table by either the application, or a routine invoked directly or
> indirectly from that application.

Because my before trigger is on the same table. How can I check the count without running into such error?

Comment: What is your question? You described what you did and the (expected) error.

Comment: my question is how can i overcome this error. or the implementation to check the count using this UDF

Comment: I added that question.

Comment: Have you tried inlining it into the trigger itself?

Comment: yes inlining works. But i have some other functionality to be executed which can be done using function only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Data conflicts when procedures read from or write to tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=or-data-conflicts-when-procedures-read-from-write-tables).
You may rewrite your function logic into a SP invocation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CheckCount(query varchar(1000), out cnt int) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN
  PREPARE S1 FROM 'SET ? = (' || query || ')';
  EXECUTE S1 INTO cnt;
END@
```

And use it in your trigger like below:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TEST_INSERT
 BEFORE INSERT ON TEST 
 REFERENCING NEW AS OBJ
 FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
 BEGIN
   DECLARE V_CNT INT;
   --SET V_CNT = CHECKCOUNT('SELECT count(1) FROM TEST5');
   CALL CHECKCOUNT('SELECT count(1) FROM TEST', V_CNT);
   IF <some expressin with V_CNT>
   THEN
     ...
   END IF;   
 END
 @
```

If you still get [SQL0746N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=messages-sql0500-sql0749#sql0746n) (I don't have 10.x at hand and don't remember, if it's needed), try to run the following on the server as an instance owner (Linux, Unix) or Local Administrator (Windows) as suggested at the description, and recreate the routine and the trigger afterwards:

```
db2set DB2_RESOLVE_CALL_CONFLICT=YES -immediate
```

Comment: Can i just used UDF instead of SP?

Comment: No, you can't use UDFs instead of SP to make it work.

Comment: This helped Thank You!!

Comment: Can you please clear my doubt why UDF didnt work but SP did?

Comment: I don't know. It's probably such a design. You may use a function multiple times in your query, and it's probably hard to get correct results with them. IBM, probably, desperately tries to prevent you from doing such dangerous things to avoid further possible annoying questions like "why did I expect this, but got that?".